# iOS Notification Images. "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessagingExtensionHelper" error

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase, xcode12

I want to add image notification to my app (https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images), but faced with some problem on the third step ([Use the extension helper](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images#step-3---use-the-extension-helper)).

When I try to #import "FirebaseMessaging.h" and then build everything I got an error

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnJc5.png)

(Have the latest firebase version 10.1.1 and react-native 0.63.3, xCode 12.2)

Any ideas please?

Comment: after xCode update to 12.3 the same

Comment: The problem was in PodFile)